# Limitar campos dinamicos no jquery

Tags: jquery

Tenho essa função para gerar campos dinamicamente, como posso por um limite de campos gerados.

```
$(function () {
    var scntDiv = $('#dynamicDiv');

    $(document).on('click', '#addInput', function () {
        $('<p>' +
                '<input type="text" id="inputeste" name="beneficio[]" class="form-control" placeholder="Adicionar beneficio" /> ' +
                '<a class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" href="javascript:void(0)" id="remInput">' +
                '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus " aria-hidden="true"></span> ' +
                'Remover beneficio' +
                '</a>' +
                '</p>').appendTo(scntDiv);
        return false;
    });

    $(document).on('click', '#remInput', function () {
        $(this).parents('p').remove();
        return false;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Coloque um contador, e se chegar no limite não adiciona mais:

```
var contador = 0;
var limite = 5;

$(function() {
    var scntDiv = $('#dynamicDiv');

    $(document).on('click', '#addInput', function() {
        if (contador < limite) {
            $('<p>' +
                '<input type="text" id="inputeste" name="beneficio[]" class="form-control" placeholder="Adicionar beneficio" /> ' +
                '<a class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" href="javascript:void(0)" id="remInput">' +
                '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus " aria-hidden="true"></span> ' +
                'Remover beneficio' +
                '</a>' +
                '</p>').appendTo(scntDiv);
            contador++; // incremento do contador
        }
        return false;
    });

    $(document).on('click', '#remInput', function() {
        $(this).parents('p').remove();
        if (contador > 0)
            contador--; // remover do contador tb
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: Valeu era exatamente isso.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function () {
    var scntDiv = $('#dynamicDiv');
    var i = 0;

    $(document).on('click', '#addInput', function () {
        if (i > 10) return false;

        i++;
        $('<p>' +
                '<input type="text" id="inputeste" name="beneficio[]" class="form-control" placeholder="Adicionar beneficio" /> ' +
                '<a class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" href="javascript:void(0)" id="remInput">' +
                '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus " aria-hidden="true"></span> ' +
                'Remover beneficio' +
                '</a>' +
                '</p>').appendTo(scntDiv);
        return false;
    });

    $(document).on('click', '#remInput', function () {
        $(this).parents('p').remove();
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: Boa resposta @WillianBrunoRocha. Apesar do AP não ter especificado, acredito que é importante tratar também caso o elemento seja removido.

Comment: Valeu pela ajuda :D

Answer (score 0):

Apenas adicionando uma alternativa às respostas anteriores...
O que você acha de apenas contar a quantidade de filhos que sua div possui?

```
if($('#dynamicDiv').children().length < count)
```